# How to find the length of a chinese phrase in a MySQL database with SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For example, this is my table, which is called example:

```
--------------------------
| id | en_word | zh_word |
--------------------------
| 1  | Internet| 互联网   |
--------------------------
| 2  | Hello   |   你好   |
--------------------------

and so on...
```

And I tried using this SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `example` WHERE LENGTH(`zh_word`) = 3
```

For some reason, it wouldn't give me three, but would give me a lot of single letter characters.

Why is this? Can this be fixed? I tried this out in PhpMyAdmin.

But when I did it with JavaScript:

```
"互联网".length == 3; // true
```

And it seems to work fine. So how come it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know an answer but perhaps SQL bases length off of bytes (in which case letters could be counted as 1 when converted but chinese symbols may be 3 or 4 when converted with that same algorithm)... There is probably something other than length you can use for looking at the actual count of unicode characters. That's my best guess.

Comment: Just saw the answer below, seems we were both thinking along the same track! Glad you got your solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `CHAR_LENGTH` instead of `LENGTH`

`LENGTH()` returns the length of the string measured in bytes. 
`CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the length of the string measured in characters.

Answer (score 1):

LENGTH returns length in bytes (and chinese is multibyte)

Use CHAR_LENGTH to get length in characters

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length